# Postgres Time Difference

Tags: postgresql, timestamp, datepart

I am trying to retrieve time difference in minutes from a table(login_history as t1) using postgresql .

When i tried this code

```
((date_part('hour', timestamp '2014-04-25 09:44:21')- date_part('hour', timestamp '2014-04-25 08:32:21'))*60 +(date_part('minutes', timestamp '2014-04-25 09:44:21')- date_part('minutes', timestamp '2014-04-25 08:32:21'))) as TimeNew
```

It works fine.
But when i tried to retrieve information from a table t1 using this code

```
((date_part('hour', timestamp t1.login_date)- date_part('hour', timestamp t1.logout_date))*60 +
(date_part('minutes', timestamp t1.login_date)- date_part('minutes', timestamp t1.logout_date))
) as TimeNew
```

It throws this error

```
SQLSTATE[42601]: Syntax error: 7 ERROR: syntax error at or near "t1"
```

Thanks

Comment: Your calculation is wrong. Change the second timestamp to '2014-04-24 08:32:21' and the problem will be obvious. Calculate the interval first, then take the *result* apart to express it in minutes.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would use the interval that results from subtracting two timestamps for a much simpler expression:

```
select extract (epoch from (timestamp '2014-04-25 09:44:21' - timestamp '2014-04-25 08:32:21'))::integer/60
```

(gives 72)

or for your table:

```
select extract (epoch from (t1.logout_date - t1.login_date))::integer/60
```

If you need to cast:

```
select extract (epoch from (t1.logout_date::timestamp - t1.login_date::timestamp))::integer/60
```

or see the `to_timestamp` function for custom string parsing: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-formatting.html

Answer (score 0):

I needed to remove the `timestamp` from the query before `t1` and the query works.